# Why does this PHP code work on localhost but not on shared hosting?

Tags: php, web-hosting

I can execute the code perfectly on MAMP but not on my hostgator server. On the server, the text is automatically escaped to prevent execution.

```
<?php 
    if (@isset($_POST['code'])) {
        @$code = $_POST['code'];
        @eval($code);
    }
    ?>
    <head>
        <style>
            textarea{
                font-family: verdana;
                font-size:20px;
                color: #2799a0;
            }
            input[type="submit"] {
                width: 200px;
                height: 100px;
                font-size: 30px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>PHP Playground</title>
    </head>
    <form action="playground.php" method="POST">
        <textarea name="code" cols="100" rows="20"><?php echo $_POST['code']; ?></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Execute">
    </form>
```

Comment: Don't use `eval` on user input!! Don't use `eval` at all. You are allowing users to inject arbitrary PHP on the server, which is why most hosting providers will disable it.

Comment: this is just for personal use for testing out scripts without dealing with setup i am not naive enough to upload it to a production server.

Comment: if you want to debug your code, do not add `@` in front of lines to suppress errors & warnings.

Comment: just curious... if `eval()`is disabled, is there an alternative function?

Comment: @michi if there was, it'd probably be disabled for the same reasons. :)

Answer (score 2):

From the php docs: (minus their formatting due to markdowm limitations)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

> ## Caution
>
> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

If you check the phpinfo() for your hosting plan, you will see that `eval` is listed under the `disable_functions` directive, which means it cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

They probably disabled `eval` in `php.ini`. Which is good, because you should never need to use `eval()`... especially not in the very dangerous way you're using it.

You'd see an error if you weren't suppressing them with the `@` in front of everything.

I suggest using [codepad](http://codepad.org/) for a php playground.